# How to store values from a dataset into an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset file called "data.mat", how can I store all the values in that into an array which I wanna name y or f(x) ?

The only thing I know is how to load it for example like this:

```
load('data.mat');
```

Comment: So what is the problem if you load the file and rename the variables, merge them or whatever you want to do? Alos `f(x)` is not a valid variable names, as brackets are not allowed.

Comment: so then I wanna nam it fx, but you dont get my point I'm not a Matlab professional, I want to store those values into an array which I call fx but I am not sure what is the simpliest way to do that?

Comment: after loading you can use the call the function `whos` and it will list all variable that are in you have. Say they are called `a` and `b`. Then you can simply do `fx = a`, if you want to store the values of `a` in a variable named `fx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load all the values in the MAT file into the struct s, which I think is the behavior you want:

```
s = load('data.mat');
```